# Full calendar wrap fc-heading and fc-item into single div

Tags: fullcalendar

Full calendar how to wrap fc-list-heading and fc-list-item into single div?

Need output like this

```
<div>
  <tr>fc-list-heading</tr>
</div>
<div>
  <tr>fc-list-item</tr>
  <tr>fc-list-item</tr>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in following way:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
  if (view.name == 'listUpcoming' || view.name == 'listPast') {
    let tableSubHeaders = $(".fc-list-heading");
    tableSubHeaders.each(function () {
      jQuery(this).nextUntil(".fc-list-heading").wrapAll("<tr class='fc-list-item-parent'></tr>");
       });
     }
}
```